# The jmeter concurrency test found 429/Too Many Requests errors

Tags: spring-boot, jmeter

I set up a web project with springboot and modified the Tomcat configuration：

```
tomcat:
    
    max-threads: 800
    
    accept-count: 1000
    
    max-connections: 10000
    
    min-spare-threads: 100
```

I deployed the project to a Linux server. The concurrency performance was tested with jmeter both locally and on the server. jmeter sets the following parameters：Number of Threads is 200, Ramp-up period is 0, and Loop Count is 1.

The local result is normal, and all requests are all accepted. However, 429 errors occurred in 43.5% of requests from the server test result.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case you have a [rate-limiter implemented](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/implement-rate-limiting-in-spring-boot/) somewhere so depending on the configuration applied you can:

1. Just turn it off via Spring Boot configuration
2. Or check your app performance within the configured maximum requests rate
3. Or try to impersonate different users coming from different IP addresses by setting up [IP Spoofing in your JMeter test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ip-spoofing-jmeter) so your server would "think" that users are coming from the different locations and apply rate limiting for each user and not globally.